# Image doesn't move in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Please, My Pygame image doesn't move but when I change the code to print and I press the arrow keys, it does work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have imported OS, random and pygame in my original code as well as set width and height to 800, 600

```
class Alien(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,speed, size):
        self.x = random.randrange(0,width)
        self.y = random.randrange(-200, -20)
        self.size = random.randint(3, 20)
        self.speed = speed

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += self.speed

    def draw(self, screen, colour):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size)

    def check_landed(self):
        if self.y > height:
            self.x = random.randrange(0,width)
            self.y = random.randrange(-400, -20)
            self.speed = random.randrange(1,4)


class Actor(Alien):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.score = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("../images", filename)).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.centerx -= 10
            print("let")

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.centerx += 10

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (width/2, height - 40))
```

In the main game implementation, i have

```
enemies = []
actor = Actor("ship.jpg")

for i in range (20):
    aliens = Alien(2, 4)
    enemies.append(aliens)

done = False
while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)
    actor.x = 500
    actor.y = 500
    actor.draw(screen)
    actor.move()

    for i in range(len(enemies)):
        enemies[i].draw(screen, red)
        enemies[i].move_down()
        enemies[i].check_landed()

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overriden the [`Sprite.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method.

The normal method, as the docs say, "uses the Sprite.image attribute for the source surface, and Sprite.rect for the position".

In your `Alien` subclass, you aren't using that, but you're instead using the `x` and `y` attributes, which might also work, because that's what you're modifying everywhere:

```
def draw(self, screen, colour):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size)
```

But your `Actor` subclass doesn't use *either*, it just blits to screen at a fixed location of `(width/2, height - 40)`:

```
def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, (width/2, height - 40))
```

So, no matter what attributes you change, you're always going to draw at the same position.

I'm not sure why you're overriding `draw` for either of these classes. I'm also not sure why `Alien` inherits from `Sprite` but then uses `x` and `y` attributes while ignoring `rect`, while `Actor` inherits from `Alien` but then ignores `x` and `y` while using `rect` again. This is almost certainly going to confuse you. But if you want the smallest possible change:

```
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Of course you'll also need to set up `self.rect` to the initial starting position at startup, and prevent the user from going all the way off the edge of the screen, and so on. And, again, it would be better to clean this up to not be confusing in the first place. But this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot abarnert. I removed the pygame.sprite.Sprite inheritance and i changed the draw method you specified above to self.rect and it worked. God bless you